# NumPy SVD Does Not Agree With R Implementation

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I saw a [question about inverting a singular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998775/python-vs-matlab-why-my-matrix-is-singular-in-python) on Stack Overflow using NumPy.  I wanted to see if NumPy SVD could provide an acceptable answer.

I've demonstrated using [SVD in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r/19767525#19767525) for another Stack Overflow answer.  I used that known solution to make sure that my NumPy code was working correctly before applying it to the new question.

I was surprised to learn that the NumPy solution did not match the R answer.  I didn't get an identity back when I substituted the NumPy solution back into the equation.

The U matricies from R and NumPy are the same shape (3x3) and the values are the same, but signs are different.  Here is the U matrix I got from NumPy:

[image]

The D matricies are identical for R and NumPy.  Here is D after the large diagonal element is zeroed out:

[image]

The V matrix I get from NumPy has shape 3x4; R gives me a 4x3 matrix.  The values are similar, but the signs are different, as they were for U.  Here is the V matrix I got from NumPy:

[image]

The R solution vector is:

```
x = [2.41176,-2.28235,2.15294,-3.47059]
```

When I substitute this back into the original equation `A*x = b` I get the RHS vector from my R solution:

```
b = [-17.00000,28.00000,11.00000]
```

NumPy gives me this solution vector:

```
x = [2.55645,-2.27029,1.98412,-3.23182]
```

When I substitute the NumPy solution back into the original equation `A*x = b` I get this result:

```
b = [-15.93399,28.04088,12.10690]
```

Close, but not correct.

I repeated the experiment using NumPy `np.linalg.pinv` pseudo-inverse method.  It agrees with the R solution.

Here is my complete Python script:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998775/python-vs-matlab-why-my-matrix-is-singular-in-python


import numpy as np

def pseudo_inverse_solver(A, b):
    A_inv = np.linalg.pinv(A)
    x = np.matmul(A_inv, b)
    error = np.matmul(A, x) - b
    return x, error, A_inv

def svd_solver(A, b):
    U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    D_diag = np.diag(np.diag(np.reciprocal(D)))
    D_zero = np.array(D_diag)
    D_zero[D_zero >= 1.0e15] = 0.0
    D_zero = np.diag(D_zero)
    A_inv = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(V), D_zero), U)
    x = np.matmul(A_inv, b)
    error = np.matmul(A, x) - b
    return x, error, A_inv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Solution from my SO answer
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r/19767525#19767525
    Example showing how to use NumPy SVD
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913232/using-numpy-np-linalg-svd-for-singular-value-decomposition
    """
    np.set_printoptions(20)
    A = np.array([
        [0.0, 1.0, -2.0, 3.0],
        [5.0, -3.0, 1.0, -2.0],
        [5.0, -2.0, -1.0, 1.0]
    ])
    b = np.array([-17.0, 28.0, 11.0]).T

    x_svd, error_svd, A_inv_svd = svd_solver(A, b)
    error_svd_L2 = np.linalg.norm(error_svd)
    x_pseudo, error_pseudo, A_inv_pseudo = pseudo_inverse_solver(A, b)
    error_pseudo_L2 = np.linalg.norm(error_pseudo)
```

Any advice on what I've missed with NumPy SVD?  Did I make a mistake at this line?

```
    A_inv = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(V), D_zero), U)
```

Update: Chrysophylaxs pointed out my error: I needed to transpose U:

```
    A_inv = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(V), D_zero), np.transpose(U))
```

This change solves the problem.  Thank you so much!

Comment: My linear algebra is rusty, but I believe, in the line you point out, `U` should be transposed too!

Comment: Worth a try.  You are spot on.  Thank you so much!  Post this as an answer and I'll accept and vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chrysophylaxs, here is the code that is now working correctly:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75998775/python-vs-matlab-why-my-matrix-is-singular-in-python


import numpy as np

def pseudo_inverse_solver(A, b):
    A_inv = np.linalg.pinv(A)
    x = np.matmul(A_inv, b)
    error = np.matmul(A, x) - b
    return x, error, A_inv

def svd_solver_so(A, b, max_diag=1.0e15):
    """
    see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913232/using-numpy-np-linalg-svd-for-singular-value-decomposition
    see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292279/solving-linear-systems-of-equations-with-svd-decomposition
    :param A: Matrix in equation A*x = b
    :param b: RHS vector in equation A*x = b
    :param max_diag: max value of diagonal for setting to zero.
    :return: x solution, error vector
    """
    U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    D_diag = np.diag(np.diag(np.reciprocal(D)))
    D_zero = np.array(D_diag)
    D_zero[D_zero >= max_diag] = 0.0
    D_zero = np.diag(D_zero)
    A_inv = V.T @ D_zero @ U.T
    c = U.T @ b
    w = D_zero @ c
    x = V.T @ w
    error = np.matmul(A, x) - b
    return x, error, A_inv


def svd_solver(A, b, max_diag=1.0e15):
    U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
    D_diag = np.diag(np.diag(np.reciprocal(D)))
    D_zero = np.array(D_diag)
    D_zero[D_zero >= max_diag] = 0.0
    D_zero = np.diag(D_zero)
    A_inv = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.transpose(V), D_zero), np.transpose(U))
    x = np.matmul(A_inv, b)
    error = np.matmul(A, x) - b
    return x, error, A_inv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Solution from my SO answer
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763698/solving-non-square-linear-system-with-r/19767525#19767525
    Example showing how to use NumPy SVD
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913232/using-numpy-np-linalg-svd-for-singular-value-decomposition
    """
    np.set_printoptions(20)
    A = np.array([
        [0.0, 1.0, -2.0, 3.0],
        [5.0, -3.0, 1.0, -2.0],
        [5.0, -2.0, -1.0, 1.0]
    ])
    b = np.array([-17.0, 28.0, 11.0]).T

    x_svd, error_svd, A_inv_svd = svd_solver(A, b)
    error_svd_L2 = np.linalg.norm(error_svd)
    x_pseudo, error_pseudo, A_inv_pseudo = pseudo_inverse_solver(A, b)
    error_pseudo_L2 = np.linalg.norm(error_pseudo)
    x_so, error_so, A_inv_so = svd_solver_so(A, b)
    error_so_L2 = np.linalg.norm(error_so)
```